# REST API > Create Product = 400 error "Please select a product type"

Tags: orders, rest-api

I'm trying to create a Product with a call to the REST API

POST https://mymagentodomain.com/V1/products

```json
{
  "product":{
    "price":8,
    "sku":"123456789",
    "name":"My Product",
    "attribute_set_id":4,
    "status":1,
    "type_id":"simple"
    }
}
```

and getting the following response from the server:

```
400 Bad Request
{
 "message":"Please select a product type",
 "success":false,
 "errors":"",
 "type":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Exception"
}
```

The attribute set ID, status and type ID are all valid for my system.

If I make the exact same call on a different Magento 2 installation it works fine, so I'm trying to figure out what could be making this fall over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this payload :**

```
 {
  "product": {
    "sku": "samsung-a50",
    "name": "Samsung A50 ",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "price": 150000,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 1,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "weight": "1",
    "extension_attributes": {
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked!  

Now I just need to narrow down which addition _made_ it work.  

Thanks Nihal!

Comment: kindly accept answer as solution thanks